# How to secure this power cable on a network switch?

Tags: networking, hp, switch, electrical-power

The device is an HP EI A5120 network switch. Is there a way to secure this power cable? Some other devices you can use a zip tie on these tabs. I searched but did not find a retention bracket from HP.

[image: rear view of network switch power cable]

Answer (score 2):

HP manuals do not explain this. My answer is based on previous experiences with other devices from Sun/Oracle, Cisco, Juniper, etc.

My understanding is those holes are designed for a cable retainer and for whatever reason, HP has not installed a retainer on the final product.

Cable retainers come in different forms; most of them include a formed u shape hard wire made of sprint stainless steel with two small 90 degrees bent ends that'd go into wholes like those ones in your picture. You can search for "AC power cable retainer" and maybe even add "Sun" or "Cisco" or "Juniper" to your search to see a variety of cable retainers.

Answer (score 2):

It feels like a slot for some springy cable retainer like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01MUZ0H03) one:

[image: Juniper AC Power Cord Retainer 760-027127]

Contacting HP should help.